# unload dynamic library needs two dlclose() calls?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa, dylib

I have a dynamic library which I load using `dlopen()` and then unload using `dlclose()`;

If I dont include any objective c code `dlopen()` needs one `dlclose()` call which is expected behavior. But when I include any objective c code to target, I have problem that I need to do two `dlclose()` calls to the loaded library in order to unload.

Is this something expected behavior? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that your library is not `dlopen`-ed twice in a hidden way? Or maybe a bug -e.g. memory leak-  is overwriting memory near the `dlopen`-ed handle?

Comment: dlopen keeps a reference count of on the library handle. If dlopen was done twice, it will require two dlclose() to unload the library. Is it possible the dynamic library is required if you include the obj-C code ? In which case the first dlopen may be done when you run your program

Comment: Yes I am sure its not dlopened twice. You can try a simple program in main with dlopen followed by dlclose with dynamic library which has objective c code.

Comment: @Finslicer: I am sure that dynamic library is not required in start of program. As I said, even a simple main with dlopen and then dlclose does not work as expected if there is objective c code.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I realize that you are using `dlopen`, not `CFBundle` or `NSBundle`.  Nevertheless, the *[Code Loading Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/CFNSBundle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001270-BCIDBAEJ)* manual says this:

> In Cocoa applications, you should not use `CFBundle` routines to load and unload executable code, because `CFBundle` does not natively support the Objective-C runtime. `NSBundle` correctly loads Objective-C symbols into the runtime system, but there is no way to unload Cocoa bundles once loaded due to a runtime limitation.

and this:

> Because of a limitation in the Objective-C runtime system, `NSBundle` cannot unload executable code.

This makes me suspect that when you load your library, it registers itself with the Objective-C runtime, and the runtime calls `dlopen` on the library again (or somehow increases the library's reference count).

I searched the Objective-C runtime source code and found [this](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/objc-os.m):

```
// dylibs are not allowed to unload
// ...except those with image_info and nothing else (5359412)
if (result->mhdr->filetype == MH_DYLIB  &&  _hasObjcContents(result)) {
    dlopen(result->os.dl_info.dli_fname, RTLD_NOLOAD);
}
```

So yes, the Objective-C runtime is calling `dlopen` on your library specifically to prevent it from being unloaded.  If you cheat and call `dlclose` twice, you should expect bad things to happen.