# dlclose not unloading nested shared library on gcc, linux

Tags: dynamic-linking, shared-libraries

I have gone through other questions on SO with no luck for eg:
[C++: dlclose doesn't unload the shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792363/c-dlclose-doesnt-unload-the-shared-library)

I have encountered with two shared objects(unfortunately i can't expose the code).
lets say

`liba.so` and `libb.so`

`liba.so` implicitly links `libb.so`.

And an application explicitly links `liba.so` using `dlopen()` with `RTLD_LAZY` flag.

Everything is working fine except that `dlclose()` isn't unloading `liba.so`, although its returning successfully. `lsof` command is showing both `liba.so` and `libb.so` as loaded.

As the answer to above question suggests, `dlclose()` only decrements ref count. But as nothing else is using those libraries I expect `dlclose()` to actually unload it.

I have tried these two so's with different application with same problem. So I guess the problem is within the libraries.

Can someone please give suggestion about what might be the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... finally it seems that the problem has been found.

That's a bug in OpenSUSE.

Here is the link:
https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=680125

The code is ran on `OpenSUSE 12.1` and the bug was resolved in `OpenSUSE 12.2`.

Comment: Any changes of somehow mirroring the link? I have 'no permissions' error when entering this page (yes, I'm aware it was 7 years ago, but still I'd like to check that page)