# libpthread.so continues to use TLS space and DL namespaces after `dlclose()`

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I'm working on a project that needs to arbitrarily load/unload Rust-based plugins (shared objects) into isolated dynamic library namespaces.

I use `dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "rust-plugin.so", RTLD_LAZY)` to create a new namespace for a shared object. When the the shared object is no longer needed, I call `dlclose()`.

Unfortunately, I've found that even when I `dlclose()` so that only one shared object is valid at a time, after `dlmopen()`ing 14 Rust plugin objects, I get the error:

```
dlmopen(rust-plugin.so) failed: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block
```

Continued attempts to `dlmopen()` after this failure result in a segmentation fault and `no more namespaces available for dlmopen()`.

I seem to have isolated the problem to the `libpthread.so` dependency of Rust shared objects. Other shared object dependencies like `libgcc_s.so.1` (and any .so files I have tried, for that matter) can be opened and closed by the following code indefinitely, whereas `libpthread.so` errors out after I open and close it 14 times.

```
#include <link.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#include <cstdlib>

void load(char const *file) {
    void *handle_ = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, file, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle_) {
      printf("dlmopen(%s) failed: %s\n", file, dlerror());
      exit(1);
    }
    if (dlclose(handle_) != 0) {
      exit(2);
    }
}

int main() {
  void *handle_;
  for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    load("libpthread.so.0");
  }
}
```

Is there some way I can have libpthread properly clean up so I can avoid this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libpthread.so.0` has `NODELETE` flag:

```
readelf -d /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 | grep NODELETE
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NODELETE INITFIRST
```

This makes `dlclose()` on it a no-op. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8795849/50617).

Given that `dlclose()` is no-op, everything else makes sense: GLIBC is configured with 16 total loader namespaces, and one of them is reserved for the main application. Once you call `dlmopen` (without calling `dlclose`) 15 times, you exhaust them all, and subsequent attempts fail with `no more namespaces available`.

Marking `libpthread` with `NODELETE` makes sense: once it's in the picture, it fundamentally changes GLIBC operation (e.g. `malloc` starts acquiring locks, `errno` switches to thread-local, etc. etc.).

> Is there some way I can have libpthread properly clean up so I can avoid this issue?

I believe the only realistic choice for you is to try to avoid dependency on `libpthread` from your plugin.

Other things you could do:

1. open a bug against GLIBC (but you'll likely wait a long time for it to get fixed). I am not sure what the implications of unloading `libpthread` from non-default loader scope are; perhaps it should be unloadable,
2. build your own libpthread.so, identical to the system one, but without the `-z,nodelete` linker flag, and arrange for this `libpthread.so.0` to be loaded as the plugin dependency (make sure this version stays in sync with the system one, or you'll see very hard to debug crashes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm wondering what you think about this workaround? I keep track of all the namespaces that have been created. After I `dlclose()` an old plugin, I `dlmopen()` a new plugin into the namespace that still contains `libpthread.so.0`.