# Linux: how can I force my process to free unloaded libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I develop both the process and the '.so' dynamic library.
I have the following scenario:

1. Using `dlopen()` my process is loading my '.so' library,
2. I load symbols and use the library,
3. After some time I stop using the the library and unload it using `dlclose()`,
4. Now I edit my library-code, fixing bugs, and then rebuild it,
5. At later point, while process is still active, I want to reload the new version of my library.
   I call `dlopen()` once more, hoping the new image will be loaded.

The problem is that even though last `dlclose()` did succeed (returned 0), and even though now I successfully reload my library and symbols, I can see that the library was not really reloaded, and the old code is running.

I understand that `dlclose()` keeps the library in the process memory for some time and does not necessarily unloads it immediately.

Can I force my library to be unloaded, or be replaced with the new `dlopen()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dlclose doesn't really unload shared object, no matter how many times it is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467404/dlclose-doesnt-really-unload-shared-object-no-matter-how-many-times-it-is-call)

Comment: check this [dlclose doesn't unload the shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792363/c-dlclose-doesnt-unload-the-shared-library)

Comment: Can't reproduce (on ubuntu22 at least). Can you show some https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: Thank you wohlstad and konchy. This link does talk about same problem, but did not offer a solution (rather said that there is no solution). STB_GNU_UNIQUE is not relevant for my case. I wanted to see if anyone found a workaround for this

Comment: A solution would be library versioning. Choose a name like `mylib.so.1`, `mylib.so.2`, ... With a simple counter, you simply load the specific version (or any other mechanism, i don't know how you implemented the reloading procedere).

Comment: @ErdalKüçük I thought about this, but then I can have problem with debugging as original module name is loaded and the new one is different

Comment: What about a symbolic link? Whenever you create a new version of your library, you create a symlink targeting the current lib. The name stays the same and if the target is required, `readlink` will give you that.